# How to define extension methods for generic class?

Tags: c#, methods, generics

I am having a generic interface as:

```
public IRepository< T >
{

    void Add(T entity);

}
```

and a class as:

```
public class Repository< T >:IRepository< T >
{

    void Add(T entity)
    {      //Some Implementation
    }

}
```

Now I want to make an extension method of the above interface. I made the following class:

```
public static class RepositoryExtension

{

    public static void Add(this IRepository< T > dataAccessRepository, T entity, string additionalValue)

    {
        //Some Implementation
    }

}
```

But I get error in the extension Add method. It doesn't recognize the Type 'T' I have passed to IRepository. I cannot event pass this Type to my Extenstion Methods class i.e RepositoryExtension< T >. Please guide the appropriate way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
public static void Add<T>(this IRepository< T > dataAccessRepository, T entity, string additionalValue)
```

Try that.
Notice the `<T>` immediately after the Add

Comment: But in this case whenever I would call this extension method I would be passing this Type. Right now I do like this: 
IRepository< Employee > employeRepository = new Repository < Employee >();
employeeRepository.Add(entity);
But in the case you suggested I'd be passing the type to The extension method too as: employeeRepository< Employee >(entity,"someValue");

Comment: Did you try it? C# and .Net will figure out the type based on the IRepository's type

Comment: yes I tried and it worked. Thanks a lot Rohith for your help. I was exactly doing the same but I was also passing the Type when I was calling the method. I tried it without passing the Type 'T' and .Net figured out:) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

```
IRepository<Employee> employeeRepository = new Repository<Employee>(); 
employeeRepository.Add(entity);
```

But in the case you suggested I'd be passing the type to The extension method too as:

```
employeeRepository<Employee>(entity,"someValue")
```

http://just-dotnet.blogspot.in/2012/06/c-generics-introduction.html